# refactoring by halting specific return of a function

Tags: r, refactoring

say `calculation.123` is my core code :

```
calculation.123 <- function(x){
 tmp1 <- x*x
 tmp2 <- x+1
 tmp3 <- 4*x
return(list(tmp1, tmp2, tmp3))
}
```

On the above, 
how would one refactor `calculation.123` that would only output `tmp2` and `tmp3` halting `tmp1`?

I would like to keep `calculation.123` original structure. That would mean a wrapping function to `calculation.123` is required:

```
wrap.calculation.123 <- function(x){
tmp <- list()
tmp <- x[2:3]
return(tmp)
}
```

hence:

```
wrap.calculation.123(calculation.123(4))
```

is there any way to inform `calculation.123` not to output `tmp1` via its argument input (or any way please suggest) so long as not to create a wrapper `wrap.calculation.123`?

Relatively new to refactoring concept; is refactor the right word for this post?

thanks

Comment: `calculation.123(4)[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple ways to do this. I would suggest using a flag to indicate, if you want to include `tmp1` or not. So something like,

```
calculation.123 <- function(x, halt_tmp1 = FALSE){
   tmp2 <- x+1
   tmp3 <- 4*x
   if (!halt_tmp1) {
     tmp1 <- x*x
     return(list(tmp1, tmp2, tmp3))
    }
   return(list(tmp2, tmp3))
}

calculation.123(4, TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] 5

#[[2]]
#[1] 16

calculation.123(4)
#[[1]]
#[1] 16

#[[2]]
#[1] 5

#[[3]]
#[1] 16
```

which is also similar to output of

```
calculation.123(4, FALSE)
```